# How to get upload progress informations for a resumable-upload with Google Cloud Storage JSON API?

Tags: javascript, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using [JSON resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) in order to upload a file to a cloud storage. But there is no information about "how to retrieve the upload progress state", in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload).

In the browser it just says "pending" until the file is uploaded.
Any idea how to get progress informations from the client or server?

Comment: The documentation talks about using the *multiple chunks* upload mechanism if you want to show progress.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't notice that part, thanks :D, if you could make it as an anwser I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation talks about using the **multiple chunks** upload mechanism if you want to show progress. That's what you need.